# How to delete an object from UITableView in Parse by swiping?

Tags: ios, xcode5, parse-platform

i want to get just one object when it is duplicated along other object in the class i don't want to get just the last object for the whole class, i want to get the last object if it was duplicated, for example

```
Name            Age       Grade       Time
---------    ------     ---------     ----------
StudentA       19          A+          01-apr-2014
StudentB       21          B-          01-apr-2014
StudentC       22          A-          01-apr-2014
StudentA       19          B+          02-apr-2014
StudentB       21          A-          02-apr-2014
```

---------------- as you can see the grades StudentA and StudentB were changing from A+ and B- to B+ and A- receptively, so i want to get this result if it's possible

```
Name            Age       Grade       Time
---------   ---------  ---------     ----------
StudentA       19          B+         02-apr-2014
StudentB       21          A-         02-apr-2014
StudentC       22          A-         01-apr-2014
```

Thank you

Comment: Why not just update the objects?, that would give you your desired output.

Comment: updating is my problem too, i don't really know how to update it from the Xcode.

Comment: Please use the `xcode` tag only for questions related to the IDE itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can update an object by adding a method to do so. I took the following code sample from the parse documentation, also, I made some assumptions since you didn't share any code. I assumed your parse class is called StudentGrade I also assumed that it has a property named letterGrade. You can change these names to match your current situation:

```
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"StudentGrade"];

// Retrieve the object by id or any other property of the student grade class
[query getObjectInBackgroundWithId:@"xWMyZ4YEGZ" block:^(PFObject *grade, NSError *error) {

    // Now let's update it with some new data. In this case, only cheatMode and score
    // will get sent to the cloud. playerName hasn't changed.
    grade[@"letterGrade"] = @"New Grade";

    [grade saveInBackground];

}];
```

The link to the parse documentation is :https://www.parse.com/docs/ios_guide#objects/iOS

hope it helps!